# _TypeError (type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, String>' is not a subtype of type 'String')

Tags: laravel, flutter, laravel-passport

I was working on some flutter project with laravel backend api. On my login page, i want to extract the user from my laravel api but it always return the error above. Here is my flutter api file:

```
class CallApi {
  final String _url = 'http://192.168.10.17/';
  
  postData(data, apiUrl) async {
    var fullUrl = _url + apiUrl + await _getToken();
    return http.post(
      fullUrl,
      body: jsonDecode(data) as _InternalLinkedHashMap<String, String>,
      headers: {
        'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
        'Accept' : 'application/json'
      }
    );
  }

  getData(apiUrl) async {
    var fullUrl = _url + apiUrl;
    return await http.get(
      fullUrl,
      headers: {
        'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
        'Accept' : 'application/json'
      }
    );
  }

  _getToken() async {
        SharedPreferences localStorage = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
        var token = localStorage.getString('token');
        return '?token=$token';
    }
}
```

And here is my backend api:

```
Route::post('/login', 'User@company');
```

Here is my implementation of the api in my login page:

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:orbital_app/Api/orbitalApi.dart';
import 'package:orbital_app/main.dart';

class Login extends StatefulWidget{
 @override
  _LoginState createState() => _LoginState();
}

class _LoginState extends State<Login> {
  TextEditingController emailController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController passwordController = TextEditingController();

  bool _isLoading = false;

  _showMsg(msg){
    final snackBar = SnackBar(
    content: Text(msg),
    action: SnackBarAction(
      label: 'Close',
      onPressed: () {}
      ), 
    );
    Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
      body: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 100),
          child: ListView(
            children: <Widget>[

              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 70),
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text('Katsana Logo'),
                    Text('Katsana', style: TextStyle(
                        fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                        fontSize: 40
                    )),
                    Text('Orbital', style: TextStyle(
                        fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                        fontSize: 30
                    ))
                  ]
                )
              ),

              Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                child: TextField(
                  controller: emailController,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                    labelText: 'Email'
                  )
                )
              ),

              Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 10, 10, 0),
                child: TextField(
                  obscureText: true,
                  controller: passwordController,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                    labelText: 'Password',
                  )
                )
              ),

              Container(
                height: 50,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                        const Radius.circular(50)
                    )
                ),
                padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 10, 10, 0),
                child: RaisedButton(
                  textColor: Colors.white,
                  color: Color.fromRGBO(42,215,157,1),
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18.0),
                  ),
                  child: Text(_isLoading ? 'Loging...' : 'Login'),
                 onPressed: _isLoading ? null : _login
                )
              )
            ]
          )
      )
    );
  }


 void _login() async {

   setState(() {
     _isLoading = true;
   });

   var data = {
     'email': emailController.text,
     'password': passwordController.text
   };

   var response = await CallApi().postData(data, 'login');
   var body = json.decode(response.body).cast<CallApi>();

   print(body);
 }
}
```

Any help would be appreciate.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are getting **String** as a response but you are explicitly converting it into **_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, String>** which is generating this error.

Comment: How to change it?